# Expressing OneHotEncoding as a linear algebra operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, sparse-matrices

In ML applications dealing with categorical variables, it is often required to transform them into a [OneHotEncoded representation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). For example, given a vector of categorical features, $x=(1,3,4,2,3)^T$, the OneHotEncoded representation is given by

$$ X = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) . $$

Is it possible to express $X$ analytically in terms of $x$?

Potentially, I am thinking of something analogous to the way [vectorization is expressed as a linear sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Vectorization_as_a_linear_sum), but I can't think of a way to turn values of the elements of a vector to corresponding elementary vectors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: Why is there a zero column between each non zero one?

Comment: @copper.hat: thanks, I modified the example to make it clearer, in general a column of zeros would mean that a particular feature does not appear in the data.

Comment: @MikeHawk: thanks for the pointer, I will need a bit more time to work through this approach.

Comment: If $e_k$ is the vector of zeros except for a one in the $k$th position then $X = \sum_k e_k e_{x_k}^T$, with appropriate dimensions for the different unit vectors.

Comment: @copper.hat: thanks, the tricky part is $e_{x_k}$ as a function of $x$, an indicator function suggested earlier might be one way...

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with it.